# How to Save Payload after sending a notifications in cloud functions?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-cloud-messaging, google-cloud-functions

How I can save a payload after sending them to specific Token in the specific node " Notifications/" to retrieve it in single screen later, 
and it saves very well,

but when I got a notification I see providerName as a **undefined** when I declare a variable "providerName"

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const admin = require("firebase-admin");
var serviceAccount = require("./serviceAccountKey.json");
admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
  databaseURL: "https://khadamatiapp-42657.firebaseio.com"
});

exports.acceptedOrder = functions.database
  .ref("/AcceptedOrders/{pid}/{orderid}")
  .onCreate(async (snapshot, context) => {
    const registrationTokens = snapshot.val().userToken;
    // const event = context.params;
    const pid = context.params.pid;
    console.log("@pid", pid);

    const username = snapshot.val().username;
    const userUid = snapshot.val().userUid;
    var providerName;
    admin
      .database()
      .ref(`providers/${pid}`)
      .once("value")
      .then(snapshot => {
        providerName = snapshot.val().username;
        console.log("pName", providerName); // here i got ProviderOne
      });

    console.log("@providerName", providerName); //here i got undefined

    const payload = {
      notification: {
        from: pid,
        to: userUid,
        title: "New Order",
        body: `Hi ${username}, You Order is Accepted from ${providerName}, check it now! `
//Hi userOne, You Order is Accepted from ***Undefined***, check it now! 
      }
    };
    try {
      let notification = payload.notification;
      const response = await admin
        .messaging()
        .sendToDevice(registrationTokens, payload)
        .then(() => {
          admin
            .database()
            .ref(`Notifications/${userUid}`)
            .push({ notification });
        });
      console.log("Successfully sent message:", response);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log("Error sending message:", error);
    }
    return null;
  });
```

## Update

I have three functions and it's a trigger in the same root,
now **acceptedOrderFromProvider** that's invoked when I create new Element in the "AcceptedOrders" Root and send a push notification

and another function is **CompletedOrderFromProvider** that's trigger if the status changed, send a notification I use an onUpdate rigger but doesn't work well, 
it's invoked when every element created or updated,

*so how to force it to invoke just when some field "status" changed?*
check here image

[image: db]

```
exports.acceptedOrderFromProvider = functions.database
  .ref("/AcceptedOrders/{pid}/{orderid}")
  .onCreate(async (snapshot, context) => {
    const registrationTokens = snapshot.val().userToken;
    // const event = context.params;
    const pid = context.params.pid;
    // console.log("@pid", pid);

    const username = snapshot.val().username;
    const userUid = snapshot.val().userUid;
    var providerName;
    admin
      .database()
      .ref(`providers/${pid}`)
      .once("value")
      .then(async snapshot => {
        providerName = snapshot.val().username;
        const payload = {
          notification: {
            from: pid,
            to: userUid,
            title: "Accepted Order",
            body: `Hi ${username}, You Order is Accepted from ${providerName}, check it now! `
          }
        };
        try {
          let notification = payload.notification;
          const response = await admin
            .messaging()
            .sendToDevice(registrationTokens, payload)
            .then(() => {
              admin
                .database()
                .ref(`Notifications/${userUid}`)
                .push({ notification });
            });
          console.log("Successfully sent message:", response);
        } catch (error) {
          console.log("Error sending message:", error);
        }
      });

    return null;
  });

exports.cancelledOrderFromProvider = functions.database
  .ref("/AcceptedOrders/{pid}/{orderid}")
  .onDelete(async (snapshot, context) => {
    const registrationTokens = snapshot.val().userToken;
    // const event = context.params;
    const pid = context.params.pid;
    // console.log("@pid", pid);

    const afterData = snapshot.val();
    // console.log(afterData);
    const username = snapshot.val().username;
    const userUid = snapshot.val().userUid;
    const nameOfProblem = snapshot.val().nameOfProblem;

    var providerName;
    admin
      .database()
      .ref(`providers/${pid}`)
      .once("value")
      .then(async snapshot => {
        providerName = snapshot.val().username;
        const payload = {
          notification: {
            from: pid,
            to: userUid,
            title: "Order Cancelled",
            body: `Hi ${username}, ${providerName} Cancelled your Order "${nameOfProblem}"!`
          }
        };
        try {
          let notification = payload.notification;
          const response = await admin
            .messaging()
            .sendToDevice(registrationTokens, payload)
            .then(() => {
              admin
                .database()
                .ref(`Notifications/${userUid}`)
                .push({ notification });
            });
          console.log("Successfully sent message:", response);
        } catch (error) {
          console.log("Error sending message:", error);
        }
      });

    return null;
  });

exports.CompletedOrderFromProvider = functions.database
  .ref("/AcceptedOrders/{pid}/{orderid}")
  .onUpdate(async (snapshot, context) => {
    console.log(snapshot.after.val());
    const registrationTokens = snapshot.after.val().userToken;
    const pid = context.params.pid;

    const username = snapshot.after.val().username;
    const userUid = snapshot.after.val().userUid;
    const nameOfProblem = snapshot.after.val().nameOfProblem;

    var providerName;
    admin
      .database()
      .ref(`providers/${pid}`)
      .once("value")
      .then(async snapshot => {
        providerName = snapshot.val().username;
        const payload = {
          notification: {
            from: pid,
            to: userUid,
            title: "Order Completed",
            body: `Hi ${username}, ${providerName} Completed your Order "${nameOfProblem}"! Check it Now`
          }
        };
        try {
          let notification = payload.notification;
          const response = await admin
            .messaging()
            .sendToDevice(registrationTokens, payload)
            .then(() => {
              admin
                .database()
                .ref(`Notifications/${userUid}`)
                .push({ notification });
            });
          console.log("Successfully sent message:", response);
        } catch (error) {
          console.log("Error sending message:", error);
        }
      });

    return null;
  });
```

Comment: The only `return` I see is the `return null` at the end, which means that the function gets (or may get) terminated by Cloud Functions as soon as that `return null` runs. Instead you'll want to bubble up the promises and return those out of the function (or use `await`), so that Cloud Functions knows until when to keep the container alive/allocated.

Comment: Hmm, any Link? I'm not understanding you well @FrankvanPuffelen

Comment: See https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/terminate-functions and https://firebase.googleblog.com/2017/06/keep-your-promises-when-using-cloud.html

Answer (score 0):

Code inside a `.then()` is run asynchronously, so even though it appears above the rest of the code in the function, it may not be called until much later. Put all code that works with `providerName` inside the `.then()` callback to ensure it is called only after `providerName` has been retrieved:

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const admin = require("firebase-admin");
var serviceAccount = require("./serviceAccountKey.json");
admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
  databaseURL: "https://khadamatiapp-42657.firebaseio.com"
});

exports.acceptedOrder = functions.database
  .ref("/AcceptedOrders/{pid}/{orderid}")
  .onCreate(async (snapshot, context) => {
    const registrationTokens = snapshot.val().userToken;
    // const event = context.params;
    const pid = context.params.pid;
    console.log("@pid", pid);

    const username = snapshot.val().username;
    const userUid = snapshot.val().userUid;
    var providerName;
    admin
      .database()
      .ref(`providers/${pid}`)
      .once("value")
      .then(snapshot => {
        providerName = snapshot.val().username;
        const payload = {
            notification: {
                from: pid,
                to: userUid,
                title: "New Order",
                body: `Hi ${username}, You Order is Accepted from ${providerName}, check it now! `
            }
        };
        try {
            let notification = payload.notification;
            const response = await admin
                .messaging()
                .sendToDevice(registrationTokens, payload)
                .then(() => {
                    admin
                    .database()
                    .ref(`Notifications/${userUid}`)
                    .push({ notification });
                });
            console.log("Successfully sent message:", response);
        } catch (error) {
            console.log("Error sending message:", error);
        }
      });

    return null;
  });
```

Comment: that's help, I have some other issue, For more details, https://i.imgur.com/BJUABEj.png I want to trigger if the status changed I wanna do something in cloud function like "push notifications", Or Check the Question again for updated @eiko

Comment: If you have time check this , @eiko 
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57164797/navigate-to-a-specific-screen-after-opening-a-notification